# How do I use YEAR ( current_year) in DB2 to get a numeric like 20230801000000 that will change with the year?

Tags: db2

I have a query in DB2 that I need to make the where clause dynamic to change with the current year.

Example:
SELECT ID, NAME, CREATEDDATE
WHERE CREATEDDATE >= 20230801000000

CREATEDDATE is a Numeric type and is displayed as such.

I have tried CREATEDDATE >= YEAR ( CURRENT_DATE ) * 10000 + 801 which results in 20230801

Comment: Are you wanting it based on the current year or does the current month play a role here too? The `+ 801` suggests a month element.

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic `DECIMAL`/`NUMERIC` with 16 digits truncated to the year can be generated by using `DATE_TRUNC` and a `CAST` to a `DECIMAL`

```sql
CAST(DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', NOW) AS DECIMAL(16,0))
```

Results:

| YEAR_TRUNC |
| --- |
| 20230101000000 |

If you are needing this at the month grain, change `'YEAR'` to `'MONTH'`

```sql
CAST(DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', NOW) AS DECIMAL(16,0))
```

Results:

| MONTH_TRUNC |
| --- |
| 20230801000000 |